# A really short code, but invalid syntax in python?

Tags: python, syntax

```
def decode(string):
    L=float(string[0])
    if (L==4):
        messageFrom4=[[string[0::L], string[1::L], string[2::L], string[3::L]]
        return messageFrom4
    if L!=4:
        return messageFrom4[0:L]
```

The second return is highlighted, with "invalid syntax error" being the issue it won't run.

Comment: Beyond the syntax error, your code has issues, and it's not clear what it is that you want to accomplish with it. You should explain in words what you want to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra `[` on this line that is causing trouble:

```
messageFrom4=[[string[0::L], string[1::L], string[2::L], string[3::L]]
              ^
             here
```

Try this instead, and do notice that `L` must be an integer if it's going to be used as a slice index, and that is a better idea to use `else` if the conditions are mutually exclusive:

```
def decode(string):
    L=int(string[0])
    if L==4:
        messageFrom4=[string[0::L], string[1::L], string[2::L], string[3::L]]
        return messageFrom4
    else:
        return string[0:L]
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line

> messageFrom4=[[string[0::L], string[1::L], string[2::L], string[3::L]]

you open two brackets and only close one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`messageFrom4` is only declared if `L==4`.

To fix this, simply declare `messageFrom4` as what you would like it to be **when L does not equal 4**.